# How to set IActionResult in .NET Standard Library?

Tags: c#, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0

I am currently creating a .NET Standard 2.0 library to handle caching with a filter.  In my `IAsyncActionFilter`, when the value is found in cache, I want to short-circuit the flow by setting `context.Result`, which is an `IActionResult`.  But, I cannot find a nuget package which gives me access to something like `Ok(testObject)` or `OkObjectResult` to set the `context.Result` to.

How can I set the `context.Result` in a .NET Standard library?

Comment: This should come from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core package I believe

Comment: You know, I saw that package and assumed it was .NET Core specific.  I just realized that it is not.  Thank you!